# Python - Grab grid data with 'onclick(event)' from plotted map

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick, netcdf

Apologies in advance for the lack of a reproducible example. The way my data is structured makes this difficult.

I'm in the process of building a program to help me collect data (in this case, grid coordinates) to train a classification algorithm. I want to be able to pull particular grid cell from my plot that I click on. I've gotten so far using the `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)` and have been able to pull out pixel coordinates using `event.x` and `event.y` (I have also tried using `event.xdata` and `event.ydata` but this seems to give me some other set of coordinates I don't recognise?) but I have been unable to extract the actual data I want.

In my code I am using the following modules:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset # reads netCDF file
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap # basemap tools
from datetime import datetime, timedelta # for working with datetimes
from random import randint
import numpy as np
```

My data comes from data stored in a NetCDF files which is a subset of a much larger model run and the variables are stored as 165*116 arrays (this is the grid dimensions). To build my plot I use the following functions:

```
def grab_sst_time(time_idx):
    """
    This reads the datetime value in my NetCDF files into local time
    """
    dtcon_days = time[time_idx]
    dtcon_start = datetime(1990,1,1) # This is the "days since" part
    dtcon_delta = timedelta(dtcon_days/24/60/60) # Create a time delta object from the number of days
    dtcon_offset = dtcon_start + dtcon_delta # Add the specified number of days to 1990
    frame_time = dtcon_offset
    return frame_time

def plot_temp(temp, time_idx, fig_no):
    """
    Plot temperature
    """

    # make frame_idx an integer to avoid slicing errors
    frame_idx = int(time_idx)

    # get 'frame_time'
    frame_time = grab_sst_time(frame_idx)

    # map setup
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0., right=1., bottom=0., top=0.9)
    # Setup the map
    m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=-38.050653, urcrnrlat=-34.453367,\
            llcrnrlon=147.996456, urcrnrlon=152.457344, lat_ts=20, resolution='h')
    # draw stuff
    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.fillcontinents(color='black')
    # plot temp
    cs = m.pcolor(lons,lats,np.squeeze(temp), latlon = True ,vmin=temp_min, vmax=temp_max, cmap='plasma')
    # plot colourbar
    plt.colorbar()
    # datetime title
    plt.title('Regional - Temperature (Celcius)\n' + 
           frame_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ' | ' + str(fname) + '_idx: ' + str(frame_idx))
    # stop axis from being cropped
    plt.tight_layout()

    return fig
```

Which when called with the correct data makes a plot like this:

[image: Example plot]

Now here's where I start getting confused. I make my plots from a random file sand time and try to make them return data I click on and save it into a database. Here's the code that calls the functions above:

```
def onclick(event):
    """
    On click function for selecting data
    """
    global ix, iy
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print('x='+str(ix), 'y='+str(iy), 'class='+str(class_value), time_value)

    global train_data
    train_data.append((ix, iy, class, time_value))

# set colour scale variables
temp_min = 14
temp_max = 24 

# list to hold data collected
train_data = []

# __Random Data__

# get list of files in data directory
directory = "/Users/directory/with/my/data"
file_ls = [f for f in listdir(directory) if isfile(join(directory, f))]
file_ls = list(filter(lambda x:'naroom_avg' in x, file_ls))

# set randomness seed
plot_num = 2
np.random.seed(1010)
rnd_file = np.random.randint(len(file_ls), size=plot_num)
rnd_times = np.random.randint(29, size=plot_num)

# __Make plots__

for i in range(0, plot_num):
    # grab file
    file_no = rnd_file[i]
    file_path = directory + "/" + file_ls[file_no]
    fname = str(file_ls[i])[11:16]
    # grab time
    time_idx = rnd_times[i]
    fh = Dataset(file_path, mode='r')
    # extract data
    lats = fh.variables['lat_rho'][:]
    lons = fh.variables['lon_rho'][:]
    time = fh.variables['ocean_time'][:]
    temp = fh.variables['temp'][time_idx,29,:,:]

    # time output
    time_value = grab_sst_time(time_idx)

    # make interactive plot 
    fig = plot_temp(temp, time_idx, i)
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

    # Select class A
    class = 'A'
    print('Select data...')
    input("Press Enter to continue...")
    plt.show()
```

This seems to work okay but I am unable to extract the data I actually want (the NetCDF data). Ideally I would like to return the grid cell (i.e. coordinates of 165*116 grid, something like x=112, y=154). Instead clicking gives me an output like the following:

```
x=432047.683555 y=449210.017634 class=A 2004-06-17 12:00:00
x=448214.625063 y=430733.513053 class=A 2004-06-17 12:00:00
x=448214.625063 y=408792.663863 class=A 2004-06-17 12:00:00
x=448792.015832 y=441703.937648 class=A 2004-06-17 12:00:00
```

Any idea on how to get my desired output?

## Supplementary data

Here's how the relevant variables of my NetCDF file are structured:

```
dimensions:

  s_rho = 30;
  eta_rho = 116;
  xi_rho = 165;
  ocean_time = UNLIMITED;   // (30 currently)

variables:

double lat_rho(eta_rho=116, xi_rho=165);
  :long_name = "latitude of RHO-points";
  :units = "degree_north";
  :standard_name = "latitude";
  :field = "lat_rho, scalar";
  :_CoordinateAxisType = "Lat";

 double lon_rho(eta_rho=116, xi_rho=165);
  :long_name = "longitude of RHO-points";
  :units = "degree_east";
  :standard_name = "longitude";
  :field = "lon_rho, scalar";
  :_CoordinateAxisType = "Lon";

double ocean_time(ocean_time=30);
  :long_name = "averaged time since initialization";
  :units = "seconds since 1990-01-01 00:00:00";
  :calendar = "gregorian";
  :field = "time, scalar, series";
  :_CoordinateAxisType = "Time";

float temp(ocean_time=30, s_rho=30, eta_rho=116, xi_rho=165);
  :long_name = "time-averaged potential temperature";
  :units = "Celsius";
  :time = "ocean_time";
  :coordinates = "lon_rho lat_rho s_rho ocean_time";
  :field = "temperature, scalar, series";
  :_FillValue = 1.0E37f; // float
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert from lon, lat to projected coordinates you call the basemap instance with the `lon,lat` values,

```
m = Basemap(...)
xpt,ypt = m(lon,lat)
```

To convert the projected coordinates back to lon, lat coordinates, you use the inverse

```
lon,lat = m(xpt,ypt, inverse=True)
```

We may modify the example from [here](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapcoords.html) to show the clicked coordinates on screen.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# setup Lambert Conformal basemap.
m = Basemap(width=12000000,height=9000000,projection='lcc',
            resolution='c',lat_1=45.,lat_2=55,lat_0=50,lon_0=-107.)

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='azure')
m.fillcontinents(color='sandybrown',lake_color='azure')

parallels = np.arange(0.,81,10.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[False,True,True,False])
meridians = np.arange(10.,351.,20.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[True,False,False,True])
# plot blue dot on Boulder, colorado and label it as such.
lon, lat = -104.237, 40.125 # Location of Boulder
# convert to map projection coords.
# Note that lon,lat can be scalars, lists or numpy arrays.
xpt,ypt = m(lon,lat)
# convert back to lat/lon
lonpt, latpt = m(xpt,ypt,inverse=True)
point, = m.plot(xpt,ypt,'bo')  # plot a blue dot there
# put some text next to the dot, offset a little bit
# (the offset is in map projection coordinates)
annotation = plt.annotate('Boulder (%5.1fW,%3.1fN)' % (lon, lat), xy=(xpt,ypt),
             xytext=(20,35), textcoords="offset points", 
             bbox={"facecolor":"w", "alpha":0.5}, 
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="arc3"))

def onclick(event):
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
    xpti, ypti = m(ix, iy,inverse=True)
    string = '(%5.1fW,%3.1fN)' % (xpti, ypti)
    print(string)
    annotation.xy = (ix, iy)
    point.set_data([ix], [iy])
    annotation.set_text(string)
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()

cid = plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", onclick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @Importance, I tested the example code and seems to do exactly what I want. I'll comment further when I've had time to incorporate this solution into my code.

Comment: Thanks @Important. Incorporated this method into my code and it works great! Cheers.